# GCP user groups?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, user-management, users, g-suite

In GCP, are we able to group users like how we do in Active Directory? I was thinking, instead of assigning roles to individual users, I can assign to groups which is more manageable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the virtual group provided by G Suite https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#g_suite_domain

Answer (score 1):

You can always manage the users by creating a [Google group](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#google_group) and then assign the role to that group. By doing so the members of the group will inherit the [role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access) given to that group.